# Iterating over excel files in a directory: Openpyxl

Tags: python, iteration, openpyxl

I am currently learning Openpyxl and practicing iterations through excel files within a directory.

My code has this error `TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'"`. I understand why I'm getting this error, I need to add another argument in `wb.save()` but I'm not sure what to exactly add in there.. I usually use `wb.save(path)` when working with one excel file but because I'm iterating through all the files within the directory...it doesn't work.

Can someone please advise on what I should do?

**Goal:**

1. To iterate through all excel files within directory.
2. Add a new sheet "ABC"
3. Save file

```
import openpyxl

import os
path = r"DIRECTORYPATH"
workbooks = os.listdir(path)

for workbook in workbooks:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path,workbook))
    wb.create_sheet("ABC")
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save to the same file you loaded from, right?
So just do

```
wb.save(os.path.join(path,workbook))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Complete brain fart on my end!